# Checking all textbox's do not contain whitespace/null value

Tags: c#, string, forms, function

I have a form that has multiple textbox's that I would like to loop through the textboxs to see if any of them contain null or whitespace. If they do then I want a boolean to be returned.

> The error I get:
>       {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type          'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'."} {"Unable to cast
>   object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'."}

My code:

```
        private bool EmptyTextBox()
    {
        //returns false if all the text boxs contain strings otherwise it will set the messagebox then return true
        /*if (!Controls.Cast<TextBox>().Any(textBox => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))) return false;
        MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave a textbox blank.");*/
        foreach (TextBox textBox in this.Controls)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave a textbox blank.");
                return false;

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how I should go about resolving this, thank you.

Comment: you should check that the control are of type textbox.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis In the "toolbox" on the designer I selected textbox's for the user to input text into. I manually changed the names of all the textbox's so I'm fairly sure they are of type textbox as they all the name textbox*number* originally. Thank you for your response.

Comment: when you get this.Controls ,all controls inside the from will get iterated in the foreach loop.this should be avoided using  this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>() instead of this.controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.Controls` will return you all type of controls. `Button`, `TextBox`, `ComboBox` and so on. In your `foreach` statement you are casting all controls to `TextBox`. This is the reason of this exception. You need to get only `TextBox` controls.
You can use `Enumerable.OfType<TResult>` from `System.Linq` namespace.

Change your code as:

```
 foreach (TextBox textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave a textbox blank.");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Or if you like one line codes:

```
private bool EmptyTextBox()
{
     bool result = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Text));

     if(result==true) MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave a textbox blank.");

     return !result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll accept your answer in four minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

You are Almost there !

```
if (!Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(textBox => 
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))) return false;
```

OfType - return only the elements of type that you provided.

Cast- will try to cast all the elements into type that you provided

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to use Required Field validator for each of the text boxes than checking it in the back end. It will give the error message without a post back.

Answer (score -1):

```
//SIMPLE WAY TO VALIDATE EMPTY SPACES
if (txtusername.Text.Contains(" "))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username");
    txtusername.Clear();
    txtusername.Focus();
}
```